# Why are ANSI escape codes not displaying properly?

Tags: console-application, ansi-escape

I am implementing a Python console application, which uses ANSI escape codes to colorize various things. I develop on Pop OS (an Ubuntu derivative), and colorization works as designed.

I just tried the app on a Centos machine, and while the colors come out correctly, there is additional text (tiny boxes containing digits, stacked vertically), surrounding the colorized text, that apparently corresponds to the escape codes.

The escape codes are all specified in this bit of Python:

```
style = ('\033[1m\033[3m' if bold and italic else
         '\033[1m' if bold else
         '\033[3m' if italic else
         '\033[0m')
return f'\001{style}\002\001\033[38;5;{color.code}m\002{s}\001\033[0m\002'
```

(The project I'm working on is https://github.com/geophile/marcel, and the above code comes from marcel.util.colorize().)

What's really odd is that in some cases, the extra characters aren't there, in other cases they are. Also, if I ssh from my pop os machine to my centos machine, the text is colorized correctly in all cases.

What explains this difference in behavior -- something in .bashrc? Something about X configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That **`\002`** is not an "ANSI" escape code.  Some *programs* (not *terminals*) may interpret it, and depending on how the string is used, that may bypass the *programs* which were intended to process the extra escapes.  (Some *terminals* may of course  provide their own interpretation for **`002`**, etc., but you're unlikely to find that documented anywhere except for their source-code).

Comment: I reread the information I found while working on colorization, and found that \001 and \002 are indeed not ANSI escape codes. Those are interpreted by readline. I found that line length calculations by readline were incorrect without these codes. So now my colorization code includes \001 and \002 when preparing prompts for use by readline, and excludes them otherwise.